# PHP Image comparsion analysis

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I am looking to store the fingerprint / image for 1 million images, so that upon upload it will shoot a % of how similar the image compared to other matches in the database. Similar to  http://www.tineye.com/ and http://images.google.com/ but for my own personal site. I do not want to submit the images to tineye using their submission process.

What information should be saved?

How should I save it?

Any good PHP libraries that do what I want already?

I would like to keep it PHP only, but I think the processing power may need to be outsourced by an application and then PHP can process the output. I am running Debian Linux.

For storage, I was going to store just the information in MySQL but I think it may inefficient given 1 million images.

Comment: The information that needs to be saved is based on how you are going to compare the images. The current question is pointless as it has infinite scope, to get an idea of the general problem, google for CBIR (Content-Based Image Retrieval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go for this PHP solution:

http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle

Even though it's a little outdated and didn't quite work with a cropped image, it was able to identify small edits, color changes, and some resizes. It also comes with example PHP code (albeit buggy)

Answer (score 1):

I think use GD, ImageMagic and it would be good to use a range of APIs. Since it is only you're site your suggesting then the API issue is not really paramount; API would be for a bigger app;

Example

```
Uploaded Image
Image information submits to Database and Image is deleted from Server and Stored in the CDN
Image information to database

Size
Dimensions
Timestamp
Uploader
Type of Image
Image Category
Image Tags
Image Description
```

You could then cron processing tasks to scan images for majority of colour on images. Shapes of images. Majority of images with text. What text. You can then build library and matching tags with these Ids as numbers. This will be patterns. You can scan for same images and matching patterns.. you can go even more deeper but then you might aswell go against Google/IBM..

Comment: Using API algorithms is a good idea. As you can get comparison databases, three or four comparison engines and compare and match closest results; therefore offering a better alternative to other systems.

Comment: Sorry my answer is a bit pseudo approach and not technical enough. For a personal site I don't know how less complex you can make such a thing!

Answer (score 0):

Such analysis is done by using complex algorithms like

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform

This one is copyrighted, but there are implementation with source code, available on the net.

Answer (score 0):

If it's "perceptual hashes" you are looking for, you could also have a look at:

http://phash.org/

They offer a php-extension, too.